# Splash Screen if there is no internet connection

Tags: flutter, webview

Hello I am new in flutter. I created a webapp with webview. Now i want that if there is not internet connection the splash screen should display that there is no internet connection other wise it should load the web page.

Answer (score 1):

in this code in initstate of stateful widget  it will check if internet is available using isInternetAvailable then it will show webview else it will show text with Internet not available.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    
import 'dart:io';
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  bool isInternetAvailable = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    isInternetConnected().then((value){
      setState(() {
        isInternetAvailable = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
   Future<bool> isInternetConnected() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        print('connected');
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print('not connected');
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: isInternetAvailable ? Webview() : Center(
          child: Text('Internet not available'),
        ) 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: sorry bro, i started stackoverflow from today so i don't have idea and it's my 1st question answer so i cannot explai very well but i improve my quality of explanation.